# Injecting 2 different rest templates in spring integration/xd http-outbound

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

Hi I have stream definition like below.Where i pull file from s3 split line by line and call http client and put to named channel.My transport is rabbit and

```
stream aws-s3|custom processor| custom-http-client --url1=https://test1.com --url2=https://test2.com --filterAttribute=messageAttribute --httpMethod=POST --nonRetryErrorCodes=400,401,404,500 --charset=UTF-8 --replyTimeout=30000 --mapHeaders=Api-Key,Content-Type --requestTimeOut=30000  |processor> queue:testQueue
```

my http-config looks like below and using apache http client for connection pooling and multithreaded I am putting back to DLQ all very errors like socket time out and retrying it .

Now my uri1 uses Oauth  and uri2 uses basic  restTemplate. How can i inject two rest template to my http-outbound? One will be oauth and other will be basicTemplate?

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <!--    <context:property-placeholder location="${xd.module.config.location}\processor\${xd.module.name}\batch-http.properties"
         ignore-resource-not-found="true" local-override="true"/> -->

    <context:property-placeholder />

   <!-- logger changes start -->
    <channel-interceptor pattern="*" order="3">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="loggingChannel" />
        </beans:bean>
    </channel-interceptor>

    <logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" log-full-message="true" level="ERROR"/>

<!-- logger changes end -->


    <header-filter input-channel="input"
                   output-channel="inputX" header-names="x-death"/>

    <service-activator input-channel="inputX" ref="gw" />

    <gateway id="gw" default-request-channel="toHttp" default-reply-timeout="0"  error-channel="errors" />

    <beans:bean id="inputfields" class="test.HTTPInputProperties">
        <beans:property name="nonRetryErrorCodes" value="${nonRetryErrorCodes}"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="responseInterceptor" class="test.ResponseInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="inputProperties" ref="inputfields" />
    </beans:bean>

    <chain input-channel="errors" output-channel="output">
        <!-- examine payload.cause (http status code etc) and decide whether
             to throw an exception or return the status code for sending to output -->
        <header-filter header-names="replyChannel, errorChannel" />
        <transformer ref="responseInterceptor"  />
    </chain>


    <int-http:outbound-gateway id='batch-http'  header-mapper="headerMapper"
                               request-channel='toHttp'
                               rest-template="batchRestTemplate"
                               url-expression="payload.contains('${filterAttribute}') ? '${url1}' : '${url2}'"  http-method="${httpMethod}"
                               expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
                               reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

    <beans:bean  id="batchHTTPConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" >
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0"  value="${charset}"/>
        <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "application/json;UTF-8" />

    </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean  id="batchRestTemplate" class="testBatchRestTemplate" >
       <beans:constructor-arg name="requestTimeOut" value="${requestTimeOut}"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg name="maxConnectionPerRoute" value="${maxConnectionPerRoute}"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg name="totalMaxConnections" ref="${totalMaxConnections}"/>
</beans:bean>





<beans:bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper"
            factory-method="outboundMapper">
<beans:property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="${mapHeaders}"/>
<beans:property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value=""/>
</beans:bean>

<channel id="output" />
<channel id="input" />
<channel id="inputX" />
<channel id="toHttp" />

        </beans:beans>



public class BatchRestTemplate  extends RestTemplate{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
                .getLogger(BatchRestTemplate.class);

    private  static Integer requestTimeOut;

    private  static Integer totalMaxConnections;
    private  static Integer maxConnectionPerRoute;






    public BatchRestTemplate(Integer requestTimeOut,Integer totalMaxConnections,Integer maxConnectionPerRoute) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException  {
          super(createBatchHttpRequestFactory());
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters= new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.addAll(getMessageConverters());
        messageConverters.add(0,new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    }

        private static ClientHttpRequestFactory createBatchHttpRequestFactory() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException  {

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory;

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory;

                socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                        SSLContext.getDefault(),
                        new String[] {"TLSv1"},
                        null,
                        SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                    .register("https", socketFactory)
                    .build();
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
            cm.setMaxTotal(250);
            cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);
            cm.closeExpiredConnections();



            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(30000)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(30000).setSocketTimeout(30000).build();



            httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).setConnectionManager(cm).build();


            httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
            return httpRequestFactory; 
    }


    }
```

ResponseInterceptor

```
public class ResponseInterceptor {

    private HTTPInputProperties inputProperties;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseInterceptor.class);

    /**
     * Intercepts the errorMessage from the API response and sends appropriate
     * information to the Output channel.
     * 
     * @param errorMessage
     * @return Message
     */
    public Message<String> transform(Message<MessagingException> errorMessage) {

        LOGGER.error("Inside Response Interceptor !");
        Message<String> responseMessage = null;
        try {
            if (null != errorMessage && null != errorMessage.getPayload()
                    && null != errorMessage.getPayload().getCause()) {
                LOGGER.error("Cause is - " + errorMessage.getPayload().getCause().getMessage());
                if (errorMessage.getPayload().getCause() instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {

                    HttpClientErrorException clientError = (HttpClientErrorException) errorMessage.getPayload()
                            .getCause();
                    LOGGER.error("Error in ResponseInceptor", clientError);
                    List<String> errorCodeList = getErrorCodes(inputProperties.getNonRetryErrorCodes());
                    // intercept Only those errors that are defined as
                    // nonRetryErrorCodes options in stream definition
                    if (null != clientError.getStatusCode()
                            && errorCodeList.contains(clientError.getStatusCode().toString())) {

                        LOGGER.error("Error in Response Body", clientError.getResponseBodyAsString());
                        LOGGER.debug("Non retry message found. Sending to output channel without retrying");

                        responseMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload((null == clientError.getResponseBodyAsString() || clientError.getResponseBodyAsString().isEmpty()) 
                                ? getDefaultPayload(clientError.getStatusCode().toString()) : clientError.getResponseBodyAsString())
                                .setHeader(BatchHttpClientConstants.HTTP_STATUS, clientError.getStatusCode().toString())
                                .setHeader(BatchHttpClientConstants.REQUEST_OBJECT,
                                        getFailedMessagePayload(errorMessage))
                                .copyHeaders(errorMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getHeaders())
                                .setReplyChannelName(BatchHttpClientConstants.OUTPUT).setErrorChannelName(null).build();

                    } else {
                        LOGGER.debug("Status code from API is not present in the nonRetryCodes");
                    }
                } else if (errorMessage.getPayload().getCause() instanceof HttpServerErrorException) {

                    LOGGER.error("Error is Instance of HttpServerErrorException");
                    HttpServerErrorException serverError = (HttpServerErrorException) errorMessage.getPayload()
                            .getCause();

                    responseMessage = MessageBuilder
                            .withPayload((null == serverError.getResponseBodyAsString()
                            || serverError.getResponseBodyAsString().isEmpty())
                            ? getDefaultPayload(serverError.getStatusCode().toString())
                            : serverError.getResponseBodyAsString())
                            .setHeader(BatchHttpClientConstants.HTTP_STATUS, serverError.getStatusCode().toString())
                            .setHeader(BatchHttpClientConstants.REQUEST_OBJECT, getFailedMessagePayload(errorMessage))
                            .copyHeaders(errorMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getHeaders())
                            .setReplyChannelName(BatchHttpClientConstants.OUTPUT).setErrorChannelName(null).build();


                }

            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occured while transforming errorResponse", exception);
        }

        // returning null will send the message back to previous module
        return responseMessage;
    }

    private String getDefaultPayload(String httpStatusCode) {

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
        if (BatchHttpClientConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.equalsIgnoreCase(httpStatusCode)) {
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.ID, BatchHttpClientConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_SUBCODE);
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.TEXT, "Internal Server Error");
        } else if (BatchHttpClientConstants.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND.equalsIgnoreCase(httpStatusCode)) {
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.ID, BatchHttpClientConstants.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND_SUBCODE);
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.TEXT, "Empty Response From the API");
        }else{
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.ID, BatchHttpClientConstants.GENERIC_ERROR_SUBCODE);
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.TEXT, "Generic Error Occured.");
        }

        return jsonResponse.toString();

    }

    /**
     * Get Individual error codes using delimiter
     * 
     * @param nonRetryErrorCodes
     * @return List of Error Codes as string
     */
    private List<String> getErrorCodes(String nonRetryErrorCodes) {

        List<String> errorCodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(nonRetryErrorCodes, BatchHttpClientConstants.DELIMITER);
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            errorCodeList.add(st.nextToken());
        }
        return errorCodeList;
    }

    /**
     * returns failed Message Payload
     * 
     * @param errorMessage
     * @return String
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    private byte[] getFailedMessagePayload(Message<MessagingException> errorMessage)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        if (null != errorMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage()
                && null != errorMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getPayload()) {
            return errorMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getPayload().toString()
                    .getBytes(BatchHttpClientConstants.UTF_8);
        }

        return "".getBytes(BatchHttpClientConstants.UTF_8);
    }

    public HTTPInputProperties getInputProperties() {
        return inputProperties;
    }

    public void setInputProperties(HTTPInputProperties inputProperties) {
        this.inputProperties = inputProperties;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - you need two gateways and a router (using the URL to route to one or the other).

Comment: Can I use 2 outbound gateways  in single module and route it to different gateway depending on payload.?I don't want to create different module.How can I do it.?

Comment: Yes; add a router; [routers are documented here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router). You can use an expression to choose the channel, just like you are using in the url - [see here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-namespace). `payload.contains('${filterAttribute}') ? 'channel1' : 'channel2'`.

Comment: Also  one doubt  i will  be  injecting OAuth2RestTemplate  from my xml  shown above with router and when i create my stream my oauth template  will be injected once .How refresh of token works because it will be injected only once ?